# Codeigniter. Checking session, num_rows() returning total count

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am experiencing a rather intriguing problem, and I have no idea why.

Utilizing the code below, if a session id is set, the echo statement returns '1' - it finds the user with that session id in the database.. simple.

If however the user has logged out, and 'my_session_id' has been set to 0 such that no result is found in the database, the echo statement seems to be returning the number of rows in the table... I.E as though the only statement was `$query=$this->db->get('users');`

Any ideas as to why?

```
$session=$this->session->userdata('my_session_id');
$this->db->where('session',$session);
$query=$this->db->get('users');

$count=$query->num_rows();



//echo $session."<br>";
echo $count;
```

Comment: you can check last query ran by using `echo $this->db->last_query();`. Can you check if appropriate query is formed

Comment: in all cases the correct query is being displayed.. *strange*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the missing session value returns zero which then causes the where part to be ignored. Adding quotes might help:

```
$this->db->where('session',"$session");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `session` column of `users` table character type or numeric type?
If it is integer, your code should work; however if it is a character type, your code is throwing following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `session` = 0
```

which will return all records in users table. It has to be:

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `session` = '0'
```

In order to do this, your code needs to be something like:

```
$this->db->where('session', (string)$session);
```

Hope this help!